# Не могу запустить обучающий курс (Golang tour)

Tags: golang

Я не понимаю, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы я смог в браузере открыть Golang Tout (Russian version).

Русская версия (Не работает) - https://go-tour-ru-ru.appspot.com/
Английская (Всё работает)- https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

При переходе на Russian version пишет: Go 1.9 is no longer available. Please refer to ***(Стек оверфлоу ругается на ссылку) for more information.

Всё что я там понял, это то, что нужно обновить Golang, но как это сделать... Ведь это всё запущено у них на сервере.

Написал в поддержку Google. И мне ответили

> Status: Won't Fix (Infeasible) Clicking on the link provided, I see
> the following error message:
>
> Go 1.9 is no longer available. Please refer to ***(Стек оверфлоу
> ругается на ссылку) for more information. According to ⁠this doc Go
> 1.9 has been shut down since June 30.
>
> To continue running your apps, migrate them to the ⁠Go 1.11 runtime or
> to ⁠newer runtimes (Go 1.12+).
>
> Please keep in mind that ⁠Google Issue Tracker is intended for
> tracking reproducible issues and feature requests during product
> development. For future reference, you may address your technical
> questions through ⁠Stack Overflow

Из этого я понял только то, что мне нужно обновить Golang, но как это сделать если это всё установлено и запушено вроде как на их сервере. (В моём представлении)

Comment: а почему Вы решили, что сайт https://go-tour-ru-ru.appspot.com/ поддерживается гугл? это похоже кто то просто сделал перевод. Как сделать что бы работало? искать автора этого сайта или сделать свой сайт. Или выучить английский.

Comment: А можно пойти [сюда](https://go.googlesource.com/tour/), скачать локальную копию и играть с ней

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже написали коллеги в комментариях, этот сайт является
неофициальным переводом *Go Tour* на русский язык. И, судя
по [его *issue tracker*'у](https://github.com/kalimatas/go-tour-ru/issues/58),
проблема известна, но автор не ответчает. Вы можете
либо пройти оригинальный *Go Tour* на английском,
либо найти другие руководства на русском. Например,
[русский перевод](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-2051-5.html)
книги
«[*The Go Programming Langauge*](https://www.gopl.io/)»
Б. Кернигана и А. Донована.